# How to correctly render the template in class based views? Django translation

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my Django APP which I give the users the opportunity to choose if they want to see the website in English or Spanish.

The problem here is that django is not rendering the correct template.

I've tried the "get_template_names" with the language session key, but still dont works...
I don`t know if the problem here is the dispatch function.

Any help or comments would be helpfull!
thank you!

views.py

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_template_names(self):
        language = self.request.session.get(translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)
        if language == 'es':
            return ['blog/home.html']
        else:
            return ['blog/en_home.html']

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         event_change_sets(Post.objects.all())
         event_change_sets_co(Post.objects.all())
         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The LocaleMiddleware is also activated.

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('es', 'Español')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `language = self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE` instead of `language = self.request.session.get(translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)`